# Create static ipv6 address without 'noprefixroute' using NetworkManager

Tags: routing, networkmanager, ipv6

I have created a static ipv6 address on my firewall (armbian) LAN ethernet. I used NetworkManager.
The problem is the address shows as:

```
inet6 2001:DB8:c101:b700::1/64 scope global noprefixroute
```

The flag noprefixroute means that there is no automatic route to 2001:DB8:c101:b700 on that interface.

I can manually create a route using NetworkManager, but I would far prefer to have the route created automatically in the absence of noprefixroute flag.

I know it can be done as I have another machine with similar configuration (debian stretch) that does have a static IP without flag noprefixroute.

```
inet6 2001:db8:c101:b700:beef::44/64 scope global
```

I don't know reason the for the difference though NetworkManager does behave rather oddly at times.

What is the best way to make the interface have a static IPv6 address without the noprefixroute flag - while still using NetworkManager?

Comment: I was running Ubuntu Server on the machine without `noprefixroute`, which doesn't even install NetworkManager (which adds `noprefixroute`), hence the difference with other Ubuntu Desktop machines.

Answer (score 6):

The Linux kernel by default adds a "device" route for each address (both IPv4 and IPv6). That is, an onlink route for the subnet in which the prefix is.

For one, that automatically added route always has a fixed metric (256 in case of IPv6). That is not what NetworkManager wants. In NetworkManager you can configure the route metric with `ipv6.route-metric` setting, which (if not specified) has a default that depends on the device type. E.g. on Ethernet, the default is a route metric of 50.

Also, with autoconf/SLAAC, depending on the router advertisement, the prefix might not be on-link. In that case, it would be wrong to add such a device route at all.

For that reason, NetworkManager always adds addresses with the noprefixroute flag, to prevent kernel to add the route automatically. Of course, NetworkManager will configure a suitable /64 as appropriate.

If you configure a static address in NetworkManager, eg. via `nmcli connection modify "$PROFILE" +ipv6.addresses "1:2:3:4::1/64" && nmcli connection up "$PROFILE"`, then you should see a corresponding 1:2:3:4::/64 route.

The "noprefixroute" flag doesn't seem to be your real problem. The flag is set for a reason. If the IP configuration that NetworkManager configures is not suitable, then there is possibly another issue.